# h2o checkpoint parameter change error - but no parameter changed??

Tags: r, h2o, checkpointing

I am trying to export the weights and biases of a "model" in which I did not originally train the model with "export_weights_and_biases = TRUE"

Therefore, I'd like to try to checkpoint the model and try to export_weights_and_biases = TRUE in a new "model2".

However, despite not changing any of the parameters - and ensuring that **nfolds=10** just as in the original "model", the checkpoint model continues to return a parameter change error almost immediately (h2o version 3.10.4.6):

```
water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Cannot change parameter: '_nfolds': 10 -> 0

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Cannot change parameter: '_nfolds': 10 -> 0
    at hex.deeplearning.DeepLearningModel$DeepLearningParameters$Sanity.checkIfParameterChangeAllowed(DeepLearningModel.java:2078)
    at hex.deeplearning.DeepLearning$DeepLearningDriver.buildModel(DeepLearning.java:249)
    at hex.deeplearning.DeepLearning$DeepLearningDriver.computeImpl(DeepLearning.java:211)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:169)
    at hex.deeplearning.DeepLearning$DeepLearningDriver.compute2(DeepLearning.java:204)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1241)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)

Error: water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Cannot change parameter: '_nfolds': 10 -> 0
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? All I'm trying to do is obtain all the weights and biases of my original "model".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this on my own:

1) Checkpoint can only be done if original model:

- used no CV
- or used CV but had fold assignment set to Modulo
- and of course if other certain parameters are not changed such as nfolds.

2) *Would still like to know how it would be possible to extract the weights and biases of my model if possible*. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming `model.dl` is a pointer to your deep learning model, you can do `model.dl@model$weights` and `model.dl@model$biases` to extract a list containing information about the weights and biases respectively. Then, loop through the list to extract the `name` attribute of the list (which returns the frame id)  and use `h2o.getFrame()` to return the frame itself.

Comment: Thank you Mauna +1. Your solution works if I set export_weights_and_biases=TRUE which I did not do in my original model. Hence my attempt to checkpoint my model so I can set it = TRUE. However b/c I did not use Modulo CV, I'm unable to checkpoint.

Comment: Any suggestion to extract weights and biases from a model in which the model's export_weights_and_biases argument was not set to TRUE?

Comment: I can't think of any way other than re-training the model. Here's the idea: Use `h2o.loadModel()` to load the model into `model.dl`. Then you can use `model.dl@parameters` to get a list of the current parameters set and add set export_weights_and_biases to TRUE. Finally, use `do.call()` on `h2o.deeplearning()` and the updated list of parameters to retrain the model.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot. While I have not tried do.call, I have tried to retrain new models with all the parameters, seed, and the dataset exactly as in the original model - but I'm unable to get h2o to reproduce a model with the same generalizability of the original model. In fact, all the retrained models have 100% failed miserably to generalize well - yet all models train, validate and test well. I think I was just lucky with my original model - and I really need to extract the weights and biases somehow. I've read it might be possible to do with POJO but I'm not certain.

Comment: POJO gives you a java file. So you could download your original model as a POJO, open it in a text editor and copy paste the parts about the weights and biases.

Comment: Thank you, Mauna. For people at my level, you've been super helpful. I.e. "If you forget to export_weights_and_biases=true and your checkpoint fails you too, then POJO is for you."

Comment: @ogukku Could you provide any additional info in your answer about where you found that information? Having similar problem and would like to read more about it.